# stop screen position going up after downloading excel file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    var downloadAsFile = function(fileName, content) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
       a.download = fileName;
    a.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+encodeURIComponent(content);
    a.click();
    };
```

```html
 <button type="submit" id="output_button" onclick="downloadAsFile()">Download</button>
```

On downloading excel file , my screen position  move up to top.so i would like screen position to stay at same position.

I know I can use "javascript:void(0)" if I'm using `<a>` tag,But in this case, i dont know how to add.

does someone have any solution or can do it in other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three* ways to stop the scroll. Explicitly return false in your `onclick` function:

```
<button type="submit" id="output_button" onclick="downloadAsFile(); return false">Download</button>
```

Or pass `event` to your function, and call `event.preventDefault()`:

```
<button type="submit" id="output_button" onclick="downloadAsFile(event, 'file', 'content'); return false">Download</button>

var downloadAsFile = function(evt, fileName, content) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.download = fileName;
   a.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+encodeURIComponent(content);
   a.click();
};
```

Use `type="button"` which intrinsically doesn't attempt to submit a form/process a link:

```
<button type="button" id="output_button" onclick="downloadAsFile()">Download</button>
```

Comment: Third: make the button's `type` `"button"`

Comment: Thank you very much I solved it by adding return false.
But why adding "return false" can stop scroll? .

Comment: Because you're explicitly telling the button not to process the event, which would normally continue with the submission.

Comment: The event you're trying to stop, is the button submitting the form. Your `downloadAsFile()` function is just something that's running when you click the button. `click => downloadAsFile() => submit form` becomes: `click => downloadAsFile() => return false => (stop here, don't submit form)`.

Comment: Ok I understand . Thank you very much